# flutter build apk create old version app even though I did flutter clean

Tags: android, flutter, build, apk

flutter build apk command keeps creating old version app.

I have done troubleshooting in several ways using:

- `flutter clean` -> `flutter build apk`
- modify version in pusbspec.yaml to 1.0.1+2
- `flutter create newproject` -> copy lib and pubspec.yaml -> `flutter build apk`
- `flutter clean` -> `flutter build apk --release`

However, none of the above method solve my problem.
The only solution is build apk in debug mode.

`flutter build apk --debug`

But the output file has a quite large size memory. Any suggestion such that I can build apk forced in the latest version and release mode?